# how can i filter the Linq results to only return selected XML column

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Just want to ask on how can i filter the Linq results to only return selected XML column, As per my XML below I just want to only return the value of `EntityId`, `EntityName`, `YA`, `ReasonText`.

```
<TASubmittedFileDT>
  <SubmissionType>ECITESVW</SubmissionType>
  <EntityId>201413671M</EntityId>
  <EntityType>6</EntityType>
  <EntityName>Epic</EntityName>
  <YA>2018</YA>
  <FileName>2018.xml</FileName>
  <Reason>0</Reason>
  <ReasonText>Successful</ReasonText>
  <TotalECI>132961837365</TotalECI>
  <Revenue>3559940928276</Revenue>
</TASubmittedFileDT>
```

Below is my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XMLFileFullName);

//code added by Reuel
//var TASubmittedFileDT = doc.Root.Elements("{http://tempuri.org/BatchDS.xsd}TASubmittedFileDT").ToList();
//XElement root = XElement.Load(XMLFileFullName);
IEnumerable<XElement> TASubmittedFileDT = from p in doc.Root.Elements() select p;
foreach (XElement e in TASubmittedFileDT)
  Console.WriteLine(e);

Console.WriteLine("GOT HERE!!!");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `where` clause to check element's name:

```
HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>(new string[]
{
    "EntityId", "EntityName", "YA", "ReasonText"
});

var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml").Root.Descendants()
         .Where(element => names.Contains(element.Name.LocalName)).ToList();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var result = from element in XDocument.Load("data.xml").Root.Descendants()
             where names.Contains(element.Name.LocalName)
             select element;
```

---

*Node that if your xml contains several `TASubmittedFileDT` elements then you'd need something along:*

```
var result = XDocument.Load("data.xml").Descendants("TASubmittedFileDT")
                      .Select(element => element.Descendants()
                                                .Where(element => names.Contains(element.Name.LocalName)))
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Gilad, Thanks for your response and code inputs. As of the moment it is outputting the correct XML node data. Just a question why the output include this information "(xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BatchDS.xsd)". This is the output data<EntityId xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BatchDS.xsd">201413671M</EntityId>. The information that is located on the top of my XML.

Comment: @Kreuel08 - then you're testing something else than the exact xml posted in question. I do not get it that way..

Comment: @ Gilad, Sorry for the confusion. this is the top part of the XML which I was not able to include in my post.<BatchDSC xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BatchDS.xsd" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<TAResultLogDT>
<ServiceId>91350111</ServiceId>
<ExtBatchId></ExtBatchId>
<SenderEntityId>201003116E</SenderEntityId>
<SenderEntityType>6</SenderEntityType>
<TASubmittedFileDT></TASubmittedFileDT>  I was not expecting that it will include some text in first part of the xml.

Comment: @Kreuel08 - this is something that should be added to the question body and not in a comment. However this is a followup question and should be asked in a separate one. 
What I can suggest is that you read into namespaces

Comment: sorry about this. thanks for your assistance will read about the namespace.

Comment: @Kreuel08 - not a problem :) If after reading you still don't understand something you can post a question (don't forget to explain what you tried/read) and if you want you can tag me in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution will be to deserialize xml to custom object.

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeModel), new XmlRootAttribute("TASubmittedFileDT"));
var doc = XDocument.Load("example.xml");
var resultingMessage = (SomeModel)serializer.Deserialize(doc.CreateReader());

public class SomeModel
{
    public string EntityId { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public int YA { get; set; }
    public string ReasonText { get; set; }
}
```